# comport programming error

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port

I connected my Bluetooth receiver with my laptop. It send me data at comport 23 continue.but me code not detected this comport. It gave me a list of in use comport. Any one know solution for this problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class  PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener  {
  static Enumeration ports;

  static CommPortIdentifier pID;

  InputStream inStream;

  SerialPort serPort;

  public PortReader() throws Exception{
    serPort = (SerialPort) pID.open("PortReader", 2000);
    inStream = serPort.getInputStream();

    serPort.addEventListener(this);

    serPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    serPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
  }

  public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.BI occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.OE occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.FE occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.PE occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.CD occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.CTS occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.DSR occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.RI occurred");
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY occurred");
      break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
      System.out.println("SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE occurred");
      byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

      try {
        while (inStream.available() > 0) {
          int numBytes = inStream.read(readBuffer);
        }
        System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + ioe);
      }
      break;
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
      pID = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
      System.out.println("Port " + pID.getName());

      if (pID.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (pID.getName().equals("COM23")) {
          PortReader pReader = new PortReader();
          System.out.println("COM23 found");
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What is in the list? Can you show us a print-out?

Comment: yes, i can show my print-out it is comport number as per System.out.println("port"+pID.getName);

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the port?

Comment: ya i checked that name they all are in used but all used port not display only few in used port name display.

Comment: What Bluetooth driver/stack/version are you using?  What version of RXTX (including x32 vs. x64) are you using?

Comment: i am using Microsoft Bluetooth enumerator and RXTX version id x32

Comment: You did not provide correct information regarding specific versions, which makes it hard to help you.  In general, certain Bluetooth drivers/hardware are problematic.  Make sure you have the latest drivers for your Bluetooth "components".  Second, Rxtx is available in different versions and packages.  Some of the forks and recent versions revised how the ports get enumerated on windows, so I assume there were issues previously. See Rxtx downloads (and forks) here: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download .  Last, be sure that if you're using on x64 system, that you are using x64 binaries.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle's Doku](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/CommPortIdentifier.html) sais:

> Obtains an enumeration object that contains a CommPortIdentifier object for each port in the system.

So, if your desired port is not listed there, it might not have been setup properly. I'd check this first.

Secondly, it may be named differently from what you expect. You should print out that list to see if there is a port named similar but not exactly as you expect.

Comment: but as property of my Bluetooth receiver it send me data over comport 23  and it seen in device manager also but my enumeration object not dispaly

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the COM port listed in Device Manager? ("Control Panel" -> "Device Manager" -> "Ports")  If not, then your Bluetooth driver is not creating the COM port (SPP) as you expect.

If you do see it there, then you might try temporarily overriding the generic port enumeration by using the `-Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COM23` system property to see if you connect.

For more information on the `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` property:

- [How does Rxtx detect ports?](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Trouble_shooting#How_does_rxtx_detect_ports.3F__Can_I_override_it.3F)
- [Rxtx does not find my device](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#RXTX_does_not_find_my_device.2C_what.27s_wrong.3F)

Also, Rxtx is available in different versions and packages.  Some of the forks and recent versions of Rxtx revised how the ports get enumerated on windows, so I assume there were issues previously. See Rxtx downloads (and forks) here: http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download .

Last, be sure that if you are using on x64 system, that you are using x64 binaries.

Comment: sorry sir i not able to get you can you elaborate your answer where i can used  -Dgnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts=COM23  and i can seen COMPORT 23 in Device Manager

Comment: Rxtx supports a system property `gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts` to explicitly specify the available com ports which bypasses it's default enumeration code. I added additional links to the answer with more info.